# OpenGL 2D Depth Perception

Tags: opengl, 2d, java, lwjgl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenGL 2D Depth Perception](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26760/opengl-2d-depth-perception)

I have a 2D RPG game written in Java using LWJGL. All works fine, but at the moment I'm having trouble deciding what the best way to do depth perception is. So, for example, if the player goes in front of the tree/enemy (lower than the objects y-coordinate) then show the player in front), if the player goes behind the tree/enemy (higher than the objects specific y-coordinate), then show the player behind the object.

I have tried writing a block of code to deal with this, and it works quite well for the trees, but not for the enemies yet. Is there a simpler way of doing this in LWJGL that I'm missing?